# How safe is it to use my body as part of a circuit?

Tags: safety, electricity

I have two polystyrene balls wrapped in copper tape. When the balls touch, the tape completes a circuit from a digital pin on an Arduino inside one of the balls to an Arduino inside the other (both powered by 9v batteries). This allows them to send information to each other via the copper tape path.

I was testing the balls out, and they were working too well. Even when the balls weren't quite touching, the signal was getting through! Turns out that's because the signals were travelling via my body. Even if I held one ball in one hand and the other ball in the other hand, digital reads on one Arduino were correctly reading the digital writes from the other.

This is actually great for my project!... unless it's not safe. So I'm looking for two things:

1. A reliable reference on what is and isn't safe in terms of voltage/wattage/amperage travelling from hand to hand.
2. A second opinion on the voltage/wattage/amperage that two Arduinos will actually pump through me (from digital pin to digital pin).

Comment: You say the tape completes a circuit when the balls touch ... do the balls have some wires connecting them, besides the tape?  Or are you just doing capacitive signalling?

Comment: @jwpat7 I guess "completes the circuit" is the wrong wording. One Arduino sets a pin to 0V or 5V in a recognizable pattern, that pin leads to a pin on the other Arduino (via the copper tape), where the voltage is read. When the balls aren't touching, the pins aren't connected.

Comment: So it is like you have two metal globes, with no wires coming out, and when they are connected you are able to detect signals between them?  If so the mechanism is capacitive and current probably is on the order of nanoamps if that.  What's your signalling protocol?  Do you have to have some min or max data rate, [Manchester coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code), and so forth?

Comment: @jwpat7 I haven't decided on the protocol yet. I just confirmed that the distinction between high and low was getting through. The data rate I need is super low (<10bps) so basically anything I use will work. The main complication is cross-talk, or negotiating who sends and who receives.

Comment: If you ever switch to a wall-adapter, make sure it's not one of those ultra-cheap chinese ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about running at 5V, then I doubt there is any safety issue. After all, 9V batteries (the sort you put in your smoke detector) just have bare terminals and no-one tells you not to touch them.

There is quite a bit of related information at [How much voltage is “dangerous”?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/how-much-voltage-is-dangerous). That link seems to have enough information that there isn't a lot of point of repeating it all here.

There is a reference on that page to someone holding a metal pole connected to a 12V battery wading through water which completed the circuit and he was unable to let go of the pole. But that is **12V** (more than twice 5V) and in circumstances where there was good conduction (his body was wet).

---

In the interests of science I set up a small test. I connected myself to a 5V lab supply via an ammeter. I grasped the terminals firmly (with dry hands) and measured about 3 µA of current. From the page I referenced above there seems to be a consensus that 1 mA would be just noticeable, so this is about 300 times less.

I found if I wet my fingers I got up to about 20 µA of current, still a lot less than 1 mA.

That page mentions that 60V is getting into the range where you might get a shock.

---

Hopefully it goes without saying that if you are going to touch metal balls then you need to be certain that 5V is the maximum, and that some sort of failure in a power supply might not deliver a lot more. But if the balls are battery powered you should be pretty safe.

---

You've added that they are powered by 9V batteries. That doesn't change my answer much. The most that could "escape" due to some malfunction is then 9V. Under normal operation you would have 5V from a digital output pin.

I measured my body resistance as being around 1.5 MΩ, which is consistent with getting 3 µA of current through it.

```
I = V / R
I = 5 / 1500000 = 0.000003 A
```

Comment: Have you tried licking the terminal on a 9V battery, they don't say you shouldn't do that either :)

Comment: Yes I did that when I was a lot younger. The pain caused me to stop doing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact the voltage is almost irrelevant. The current is the issue. 30mA is normally considered the limit - this is the value [RCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device) are set to trigger at.

Even low voltages applied to intimate places can be fatal. (I have a couple of wires in my heart, these can certainly cause a significant impact).

There is little risk with the low energy available, but if you want to be safe you can use a series resistor. I have (a very early) touch sensor installed on lights in my house. The touch pad is effectively connected to 240V, but is quite safe as the pad is connected through 2 10MΩ resistors. (2 are needed as they are rated at 500V.)

Comment: *2 are needed* - plus that is a precaution if one fails and becomes closed circuit.

Comment: *In fact the voltage is almost irrelevant. The current is the issue.* - Check out ["It's not the volts that kill you, it's the amps"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xONZcBJh5A)

Comment: @NickGammon I didn't "read" the link, because it is to a video. Like most such issues this is not simple, because people are not a simple linear resistance. I bow to the recommendations of the of the Standards authorities, which admittedly only apply to "Low Voltage" (contrary to most expectations this is 1000V - with its own caveats).

Comment: If you had "read" the link you would see that he agrees with you. It isn't simple. Higher voltages, however, break down the surface resistance of things like bodies.

Comment: @NickGammon, apparently there are no wires coming out of the spheres (see comments to question) so typically any volts or amps occuring will be from capacitive effects as a few nanocoulombs of charge move around.

Comment: @jwpat7 - not wires, but he said in the question *I have two polystyrene balls wrapped in copper tape.*. I count the copper tape as "wires".

Comment: @NickGammon, ok, but no additional wires that can complete an electrical circuit per se.  Toggling a bit in the Arduino inside a ball shifts the shell up or down relative to the matter inside the ball, which I think has a capacitive effect.  If no wires come out (besides the shell) then no steady current can flow.

Comment: @jwpat7 - yessss, but the OP said *When the balls touch, the tape completes a circuit*. So I am reading that as "there is conductive stuff *on the outside* that completes the circuit" - not a capacitance effect. His surprise was that by holding the balls in each hand his body completed the circuit.

Comment: @jwpat7 If you want to have a discussion why not do it in Chat, rather than in Comments to this Answer